# Passing JSON variable into PowerShell script in Azure Pipeline

Tags: azure-pipelines, powershell-4.0

I'm trying to pass a JSON object from a file into a PS script inside an Azure Pipeline.

However, Pipeline kept coming back with the following message (bold formatting is mine).  I have been banging my head against this brick wall for a while now with this issue.  I have JSON-linted the JSON string and it all passed.  Hopefully someone has seen this out there and can provide some pointers.  Once the JSON variable was replaced with a String variable, all went well.

> C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /D /S /C ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\wbin\az.cmd" account set --subscription e7c5ee2d-c4a6-4f6c-86e6-09172501d1b3"
> C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoLogo -NoProfile -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command ". 'D:\a_temp\azureclitaskscript1661670809684.ps1'"
> D:\a\1\s\resources\TestScript.ps1 : **A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument
> 'accounts: [ { userID: 111111111 } ] }'.**
> At D:\a_temp\azureclitaskscript1661670809684.ps1:3 char:1
>
> - . 'D:\a\1\s\resources\TestScript.ps1' -usersJson "{ "acco ...
> - ```
>   + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [TestScript.ps1], > > > ParentContainsErrorRecordException
>   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,TestScript.ps1
>   ```

Pipeline code - test.yml

```
name: Test
trigger: none

pool:
  vmImage: windows-latest

parameters:
- name: env
  type: string
  values:
  - dev
  default: dev
- name: sub
  type: string
  values:
  - MySC
  default: MySC

stages:
- stage: testing
  displayName: testing
  variables:
    - template: Variables/testingJson.yml
  jobs:
  - deployment: Build
    environment: Dev
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
            - checkout: self
            - script: |
                echo "userJson - " $(usersJson)
            - task: AzureCLI@2
              inputs:
                azureSubscription: ${{ parameters.sub }}
                scriptType: ps
                scriptLocation: scriptPath
                scriptPath: resources/TestScript.ps1
                arguments: >
                  -usersJson "$(usersJson)"
                failOnStderr: true
```

Variable file (testingJson.yml) as follows

```
variables:
  usersJson: '{
                "accounts": [
                  {
                    "userID": "111111111",
                    "UPN": "test@gmail.com"
                  }
                ]
              }'
```

While the PS script (TestScript.ps1) is just there to receive the JSON variable

```
param(
  [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)][string] $usersJson
)

Write-Host "Inside PS"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you call parameters with  double quote like this
TestScript.ps1 -usersJson "$json"
You need to call with:
TestScript.ps1 -usersJson '$json'

Comment: Wow, thank you! That works and it keeps the JSON input as JSON object.

Answer (score 0):

The way to stop this is to do the following in the PS script - BUT see the accepted answer above for the correct resolution

```
param(
  [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)][string]$usersJson,
  [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)][string]$usersJson1
)

Write-Host "Inside PS " $usersJson
Write-Host "Inside PS1 " $usersJson1
```

This will take care of the 2 parameters passed in, and yes, it's one JSON object but somehow was treated as two 'objects'?